# SQL Normalizing array of tables into multiple new tables

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization

I have a database with 51 tables all with the same schema (one table per state). Each table has a couple million rows and about 50 columns.

I've normalized the columns into 6 other tables, and now I want to import all of the data from those 51 tables into the 6 new tables. The column names are all the same, and so I'm hoping I can automate the process of importing all the data.

I'm assuming what I'll need to do is:

1. Select the names of all the lists that have the raw schema

   ```
   SELECT TABLE_NAME 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'raw'
   ```
2. Iterate over all the results
3. Grab all rows from that table, and `SELECT INTO` the appropriate cols into the appropriate tables
4. Delete row from raw table

Is there anything I'm missing? Also, is there any way to have this run on the SQL Server so I don't have to have my SQL Server Management Studio open the whole time?

Comment: Once you have the script, you can always execute it using the [`SQLCMD` command-line utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, obviously, you can automate it with t-sql. But I recommened you to use SSIS in this case. As you say, structure of all tables are the same than you can make some ETL process and then you just change table name in the source. Consecuently, you will have the folowwing advantages:

1. Solve issue with couple of clicks
2. Low risk of errors
3. You will able to use the number of data transformations